# Select data from tables in SQL

Tags: sql, select

I have these tables and I want to select my messages and my friends' messages.

```
CREATE TABLE Friends
(
    userId int,
    friendId int,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(userId, friendId)
);

CREATE TABLE Message 
(
    id       int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    date     datetime,
    text     text,
    urlPhoto varchar(255),
    type     varchar(255),
    idAuthor int,
    idTarget int
);
```

Assuming my id is 1, it's easy to select my friends' ids:

```
SELECT friendId FROM Friends WHERE userid = 1;
```

but I can't use that id to select the messages.

Comment: If you can't use the userid to select the messages, what can you use?

Comment: @Mureinik I can, but I don't know how to do it. My bad.

Comment: Is idAuthor an userId? Then a foreign key constraint should be declared.

Comment: Now it's clearer, thanks

Comment: @Sergeon yes, it's supposed to be the same.

Comment: Friends table states that a user userId has a friend whose userId is the friendId? If that is the case, you should use a many to many relation I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a subquery on the `friends` table and use the ID from there. Assuming, as in the original question, your id is 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM   message
WHERE  idAuthor = 1 OR
       idAuthor IN (SELECT friendId
                    FROM   friends
                    WHERE  userId = 1)
```